File on exFAT formatted drive doesn't have an owner
I've got a file on my external drive (only used on one machine, on windows) formatted with exFAT that Windows has decided doesn't have an owner. Every other file in the same directory was created the same way (unzipped from a zip file) and shows in the details menu that the owner is "Everyone", but this particular file has that field blank. As well, attempting to delete, rename, copy, etc. the file shows a popup saying that I require permission the computer's administrator to make changes to this file.
Trying to do any of these actions in an elevated powershell even with -Force options don't work either. I tried using Get-ACL, and that also errors (and works with other files in the same directory). Similarly with takeown.
Trying to use ls in this directory on WSL acknowledges that there is a file called that in that location, but when ls tries to stat that file, it comes back with an error saying it doesn't exist.
How can I take ownership of this file? I'm just interested in deleting it.

Have you tried doing this from CMD (not PowerShell)  as Administrator? Also, try the 8.3 filename and/or use wild cards -- pernicious files may have odd character, e.g., NBS, which appears the same as space, but is CHR(160),  not CHR(32).
